# Using JQuery how to check if any checkboxes are checked and then set the first to checked if none are?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery how to check if any checkboxes are checked and then set the first to checked if none are checked.

```
var Checked = $('.ProductImageGallery').find(".DfaultCheckbox:selected);

if (Checked == null) { $('.DfaultCheckbox:first').attr('checked', true) }
```

Comment: @JohannesKlauß - That would be the bit that starts "how to check". (But yes, it could've been worded better, and an actual question mark would've been nice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select checked checkboxes with the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/), and then test the `.length` of the returned jQuery object to see if any elements matched:

```
if ($(".ProductImageGallery .DfaultCheckbox:checked").length === 0)
   $(".DfaultCheckbox:first").prop("checked", true);
```

Further reading: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Note: I've used the [`.prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) rather than `.attr()`, but `.prop()` only works if you're using jQuery 1.6+ (otherwise stick with `.attr()`).